# A noun that describes a person or group that sees all sides of an argument but doesn't have any opinions on it or make any judgements?

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a noun that describes a person or group of people that see all sides of an argument, but not take any sides or make any judgements from those sides. They simply acknowledge all sides of the argument and, as an example, if they were a news source, they display that information for the reader to decide their view on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

An *impartial observer* or *dispassionate observer*.

**Impartial**

> not partial or biased : treating or affecting all equally

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impartial)

or **dispassionate**.

> not influenced by strong feeling 
> especially : not affected by personal or emotional involvement

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispassionate)

Comment: OP asked for a noun.

Comment: One can be impartial and still make a judgment on the matter. That's precisely what is expected of a judge in a court of law, for example. The OP wanted a word for somebody who abstains from making judgments.

Comment: Noun phrase: "**neutral source**"

Comment: Though the OP asks for a noun, it may well be a more reasonable alternative to provide an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **fence-sitter**

**fence-sitting**

> a state of indecision or neutrality with respect to conflicting positions

Or you could go with

**fly on the wall**

> having or involving an inconspicuous but effective point of observation
> *fly-on-the-wall observations of aspects of daily life*
> — Will Manley

Or perhaps

**armchair**

> 1.remote from direct dealing with problems : theoretical rather than practical
> armchair strategists

> 2: sharing vicariously in another's experiences
> an armchair traveler

[Merriam-Webster]